# Invoke Blazor Webassembly C# Method from ServiceWorker for push notifications

Tags: service-worker, blazor-webassembly, webassembly, web-push

I would like to call a C# Method when WebPush get's fired. But seems like the WebAssembly Application is not available to the ServiceWorker.

This is my Code so far:

```js
// serviceworker.js
self.addEventListener('install', async event => {
    console.log('Installing service worker...');
    self.skipWaiting();
    
});

self.addEventListener('push', event => {
    const payload = event.data.json();
    console.log('push incoming', payload);
    // Create a Broadcast Channel with a specific name
    const broadcastChannel = new BroadcastChannel('bntPushMessageChannel');

    // Send a message to all listening contexts
    broadcastChannel.postMessage(payload);

    // Close the channel when it's no longer needed
    broadcastChannel.close(); 
});
```

```html
// index.html

...
   <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script src="pushNotifications.js"></script>
    <script>navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.es5.min.js');</script>    
    <script>
        const broadcastChannel = new BroadcastChannel('bntPushMessageChannel');

        // Listen for incoming messages
        broadcastChannel.onmessage = event => {

            DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('bntBackOffice.Client', 'PushMessageReceived', event.data.message);
        };
    </script>
    ...
```

```
public static class PushHandler
{
    static public INotificationService NotificationService { get; set; }

    [JSInvokable("PushMessageReceived")]
    public static async Task PushMessageReceived(string message)
    {
        if (NotificationService.PermissionStatus == PermissionType.Default)
        {
            await NotificationService.RequestPermissionAsync();
        }

        if (NotificationService.PermissionStatus == PermissionType.Granted)
        {
            await NotificationService.CreateAsync(message, new NotificationOptions() { });
        }
    }
}
```

A bit of a Nasty Part:

```
// Instantiation Config in Program.cs
PushHandler.NotificationService = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<INotificationService>();
```

Everything works as expected, as long as the website/browser is opened. When I install the PWA, close it, no Notifications are showing.

From my understanding it should be one of the top advantages using a serviceworker in this kind of structure. Running heavy background tasks could be very efficient like this.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Your Blazor WASM cannot listen on the BroadcastChannel when it is not running. Your service worker can check if a window is running via clients.matchAll({ type: "window" }) and give it focus. If none are found it can start one with clients.openwindow. Focus and openwindow methods may need to be called in the notificationclick event and may not be callable from the push event. [MDN Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowClient/focus) You may want to save the event data to IndexdDB, a cache, or add paramters to the openwindow url so the app can process it when it loads